Beta regression-dealing with small number of 0,1 values
I have a small dataset for 100 participants.
The dataset includes repeated 'tests' over a course of a week. A test can have the binary outcome of pass or fail, and the same number of tests are not necessarily completed each day. Additionally, there covariates, some of which change, for example 'day', and 'mood', while others remain the same as they are measured at the start of the week ('weight', 'height'). I would like to model the distribution of the proportion of passes, and see how the distribution changes based on the covariates. Below is a sample of the data.



ID
day
count_tests
pass
prop
mood
height
weight




1
1
24
18
0.75
1
127
74.5


1
2
23
20
0.87
2
127
74.5


1
3
24
17
0.71
2
127
74.5


1
4
20
17
0.85
1
127
74.5


1
5
21
20
0.95
2
127
74.5


......
.....
.............
......
......
......
........
........


100
1
23
20
0.87
1
190
82


100
2
24
18
0.75
3
190
82


100
3
18
9
0.5
2
190
82


100
4
21
4
0.19
1
190
82


100
5
23
20
0.87
3
190
82



I do have 15 rows out of 750 where the proportion is equal to 0 or 1. These proportions are the result of a small number of tests (<=10) being performed on that day, for example:



ID
day
count_tests
pass
prop
mood
height
weight




50
1
1
1
1.0
1
120
70


68
7
2
0
0
1
135
66


79
1
6
0
0
2
145
90.4


8
1
10
10
1.0
1
127
74.5



I am new to beta regression, so I am still learning about the appropriate use cases. Since beta regression cannot handle y outside of the 0,1 bounds, I cannot use the traditional approach. My question is, should I transform the 0s and 1s since I do not think they are accurate representation of 0 or 1 with a strategy such as $y’ = (y(N - 1) + 0.5)/N$ (Smith & Verkuilen, 2006), or would ZOIB be a more appropriate model for this data?

Since you’re counting the number of successes in binary tests, why wouldn’t you use a binomial instead of a beta regression?

I am 100% on board with modeling this as a binomial distribution.

Hi @Sycorax and Dave, thank you for your responses. Do you mean modelling the outcome of 0 or 1, as opposed to the proportional data?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_regression

Thank you @Sycorax for sharing this resource. I guess I am still unsure of how I would use binomial regression with this data when it is grouped at the level of participant and day, rather than aggregated by covariates. Would it be possible to retain the individual observations when modeling this as a binomial distribution?

That seems like a perfectly fine thing to ask in a question.
